# Flutter crashed on startup in api 19

Tags: flutter, crash, startup

Creating a new flutter project always crashed on startup in api 19, it's works fine in api above 19.

In the `flutter run -v`, the log freezes in `Waiting for observatory port to be available..`

Running `flutter doctor -v`: `No issues found!`

There is some solution for a flutter app works fine at least in api 19?

Answer (score 0):

crashes for me as well (emulator), but seems to be [known bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20091#issuecomment-490070527)

At least seems like `--release` mode doesn't have that issue.

Please, use *"add reaction"* on the initial comment to increase priority.